# Why does my image keep repeating itself?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have my images in CSS as background because i don't want them to be highlightable (hold left click and go over the stackoverflow logo. see you cant)
When i use the img element it becomes hightlightable.
now to my question

I don't understand why my logo keeps repeating itself...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hail Coding!!</title>
<style>
#page {
    font:5px;
    width:2000px;
    font-family:verdana;
    background-color;#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}
#header {
    height:217px;
    width:1000px;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/oBD9Got.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    background-size:120px 120px;
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">       
            <p id="slogan">Hail Coding!</p>
            <a href="introppage.html"id="logo"</a>




        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot to put ">" before </a>. Make it like this <a href="introppage.html"id="logo"></a>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are missing the `>` on the opening `<a>` tag.

change this: `<a href="introppage.html"id="logo"</a>`

To this: `<a href="introppage.html"id="logo"></a>`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/9juemx9p/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend your take the styling out of the head tag and into a separate .css file.

Ok - onto the problem at hand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hail Coding!!</title>
<style>
#page {
    font:5px;
    width:2000px;
    font-family:verdana;
    background-color;#FFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
 #header {
    height:217px;
    width:1000px;
 }

 #logo {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/oBD9Got.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    background-size:contain;
    display:block;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">       
           <p id="slogan">Hail Coding!</p>
           <a href="introppage.html"id="logo"></a>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So remember to always close the tags. In this case, the  was missing >. Plus, you can always "contain" the the `background-size`.

I recommend reading up on CSS at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) in particular, their superb Almanac for tips, patterns and general awesomeness.

Good luck and have fun!